# this.props.history.push() skips middle page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I checked out the tutorials and working on a small project related to routers.
I have 3 pages in my project right now.namely Login, Verify and Home. on all the pages i have a submit button like follows.

```
<button type="submit"  onClick= {this.onSubmit()}>next page name</button>
```

my onSubmit methods on login and verify page are as follows respectively:

```
this.props.history.push('/verify');
this.props.history.push('/home');
```

these are my imports:

```
import { 
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
NavLink,
useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";
```

**When there was no Home page**, navigation from login page to verify was very good;
but **when I added third page**; the "Home" page, **when I click the submit** Button on **Login** page, **it directly takes me** to the "**Home**" Page skipping the "**Verify**" page.

Please guide me where I'm going wrong! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the button code to something like this :

```
<button type="submit" onClick= {()=>this.onSubmit()}>next page name</button>
```

or something like this :

```
<button type="submit" onClick= {this.onSubmit}>next page name</button>
```

because it the onClick gets a callback function and you are calling a function in it instead

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a synchronous action so it does load the `/verify` route, but it changes too quickly to the `/home` route. If you want to load the `/verify` correctly you can redirect to home from within the route, not in the `onSubmit` method.

Also, as Mahdi mentions, you shouldn't call the function directly from the `onClick`. You need to pass a callback:

```
<button type="submit"  onClick= {this.onSubmit}>next page name</button>
```

For more information on this please to refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).